# External Monitor color profile keeps resetting

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce, intel-graphics, color-profiles

I spent hours reading on the web trying to solve the problem, but nothing seems to work for me.

I have Dell XPS15 laptop and recently bought a Dell S2240M monitor to use with it. Laptop's monitor uses Intel HD graphic card, while the external one uses NVidia.
I also used Eye-One to create color profile for my monitors (I want to use the same one for both). BUT, everytime I reboot my computer it resets the external monitor profile to default and I can't even change it. I'm not sure if it changes the laptop profile, because I can't easily tell the difference between defaults and the calibrated profile.

Solutions I tried and they didn't work:

1. Set the system default settings in Advanced Display settings (I set use Windows to calibrate).
2. Disabling persistence module using Autoruns (oddly I had to also disable it from start-up menu).
3. I read that I have to disable Intel User Interface from start-up, but I have nothing like this in startup menu. The things from Intel are: hkcmd Module, igfx Tray (enabled) and persistence module which is now disabled. But I feel that if the second monitor uses Nvidia card, Intel Modules can't affect it
   .
4. I can't find anything related to color profiles in Nvidia panel. Color management is set to another application.

Any advices?? Please, help!
Thanks!

UPDATE: Now, photoshop doesn't change the color of the photo when I move it to the second display. I mean it would usually use color profile settings of the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question when dealing with a similar issue, although with me it was a Dell U2718Q (Ultrasharp 4K) monitor, used with a Windows 7 laptop, and the color profile was resetting to "Standard" not only on reboot but every time I pressed Alt-Tab — very irritating.

I launched the "Dell Display Manager" (from the right-click menu on clicking the desktop directly) and found it was in "Auto Mode" rather than "Manual Mode."  In auto mode you can have a different color profile set on a per-application basis.

I set it back to "Manual Mode" and the problem disappeared.